# Pass in Additional Props to Div - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was wondering if there was any way to send additional props to a `div` tag in react? I am trying to create custom radio buttons, and was hoping to add another prop to represent the type of data the specific radio button was dealing with.

This is my JSX:

```
<div className="selection" value={this.state.event.name} onClick={(item) => this.selectedChoice(item, "yes")}></div><p>Yes</p>
```

but when I run:

```
selectedChoice(selected, response) {
    console.log(selected.target.value)        
}
```

the console outputs `undefined` rather than the event name, which has been defined and is displaying elsewhere just fine. From what I understand, `value` is not a prop for `div` tags and figured that's why it displayed `undefined`. I considered adding `this.state.event.name` as a class, however it seems as though I cannot do something like `className="selection {this.state.event.name}"`. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `data-` prop:

```
<div data-value={this.state.event.name}>
```

Then:

```
console.log(selected.target.getAttribute("data-value"));
```

Comment: Whoops, I did have `console.log(selected.target.value);`, I guess I forgot to include that in the initial question, I'll update my question to reflect that. But even with `selected.target.value` I receive `undefined`.

Comment: I saw your `class` thing - and yes, `value` usually isn't a value for `div`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks!

Comment: No worries @Sal, always glad to help